# Subversion update from PHP on Mac OS X?

Tags: php, macos, svn, shell-exec

I'm trying to update a subversion working copy with PHP on OS X.

```
$svnuser     = "<username>";
$svnpassword = "<password>";
$path        = "/Users/username/Projects/MyProject";

$command     = "svn update --username $svnuser --password $svnpassword $path";
$output      = system(escapeshellcmd($command));
```

The above command works on Windows (with a Windows-style path, of course), but not on OS X.
Also not getting any display of a warning or error.

Tried using a full path to the svn command, but that didn't work either. File permissions on the folder that needs to be updated, are set to read/write for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set error_reporting(E_ALL); to see the output

Comment: try   replace $command   with  **svn update --no-auth-cache --username $svnuser --password $svnpassword $path 2>&1 &**   and check directory rights, maybe **chmod 777 -R**